Как правильно указать директорию через .bat
Есть вот такой код в .bat для удаления Cache, но при входе в систему под разними пользователями приходиться его править в ручную.
del C:\Users\TestUser1\AppData\Local\MyProgram\Config\CacheStorage.*

Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз править "TestUser1" на тот под которым я сейчас авторизирован?

del %userprofile%\AppData\Local\MyProgram\Config\CacheStorage.* - как то так
